# Wordpress install with Docker doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile, localhost, port

I'm completely beginner with Docker and I'm trying to install wordpress (without database) from a base ubuntu 20.04 image with docker. I'm using apache server for this.

Here is my wordpress2_ms.dockerfile:

```
FROM  ubuntu:20.04 as baseimage
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt update && apt install -y wget tar curl sudo systemctl
RUN apt install -y php libapache2-mod-php
RUN wget -c http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
RUN tar xzvf latest.tar.gz -C /var/www/html
RUN sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/html/wordpress

FROM baseimage as wordpressapp
COPY wordpress.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
WORKDIR /etc/apache2/sites-available
RUN sudo a2ensite wordpress.conf
RUN sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
RUN sudo systemctl reload apache2
EXPOSE 80
```

For this, we have to place a context folder beside this wordpress2_ms.dockerfile, and inside this context folder we need the following wordpress.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
        ServerName localhost

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
```

The building command: sudo docker build -t wordpress:1.0 -f ./wordpress2_ms.dockerfile --target wordpressapp ./context/

The run command: sudo docker run -td --name wordpress_cont -p 8081:80 wordpress:1.0

After the run command I get the log that the wordpress has started at port 80 of the container, but nothing is happening at 8081 port of my host machine.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your Docierfile, `RUN sudo systemctl reload apache2` just run (or not) at build time. It may not work at running time. It world better (MUST) use other way to start your web server like `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.  REFER this https://medium.com/swlh/docker-and-systemd-381dfd7e4628

Comment: There are ready-made Wordpress images available if you want something easy to set up.  https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress

Comment: Apart from specific cases (e.g. emulating a full blown system for testing purpose), running iniit/systemctl inside a docker image is usually non-sense. If you want to install apache and/or php/wordpress by yourself, you should at least study how it is done in the official images available on dockerhub for each of those components and see the used commands. You will learn a lot. My 2 cent: for almost any php application running inside docker, you should prefer using a separate php-fpm container to execute php scripts called by an other container running your web server (nginx or apache).